# Can I get all the values of HashMap elements, having the same keys? (Java)

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I have a task given me on the Java programming course. According to this task I have to create a method that returns a number of the HashMap elements with identical keys. But the problem is that the iterator goes through elements with different keys only, so anyway, the method returns 1. What`s the way out?

```
package com.javarush.test.level08.lesson08.task03;

import java.util.*;

/* Одинаковые имя и фамилия
Создать словарь (Map<String, String>) занести в него десять записей по   принципу «Фамилия» - «Имя».
Проверить сколько людей имеют совпадающие с заданным имя или фамилию.
*/

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> friends = createMap();
        getCountTheSameLastName(friends, "гладких");
        getCountTheSameFirstName(friends, "Виталий");
    }

    public static HashMap<String, String> createMap()
    {
        HashMap<String, String> name = new HashMap<String, String>();

        name.put("гладких", "Иван");
        name.put("пересыпкин", "Артем");
        name.put("пересыпкин", "Владислав");
        name.put("халитов", "Виталий");
        name.put("чернышев", "Виталий");
        name.put("ивинских", "Виталий");
        name.put("ивинских", "Альфред");
        name.put("осипова", "Мария");
        name.put("ивинских", "Павел");
        name.put("гейтс", "Билл");

        return name;
    }

    public static int getCountTheSameFirstName(HashMap<String, String>         map, String name)
    {
        int MatchesFirstnameCount = 0;

        for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> pair : map.entrySet()) {
            String s = pair.getValue();
            if (s.equals(name) ) {
                MatchesFirstnameCount++;
            }
        }

        return MatchesFirstnameCount;
    }

    public static int getCountTheSameLastName(HashMap<String, String>     map, String lastName)
    {
        int MatchesSecondnameCount = 0;

        for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> pair : map.entrySet()) {
            if (pair.getKey().equals(lastName))
                MatchesSecondnameCount++;
        }
        return MatchesSecondnameCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would the HashMap contain multiple entries for the same key?

Comment: You can't have different elements with the same keys, period.

Comment: Are you certain you understood the task correctly? Maybe you were to count the number of keys with the same values?

Comment: [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) implements [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Javadoc of `Map` says: ***A map cannot contain duplicate keys.*** What you're asking for is meaningless!

Comment: Maps always should have unique keys. If you add two elements with the same key in Java, the old element would be overwritten by the new one.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a trick question.  Each key in a HashMap can only have one value associated with it.  Each key in a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) must be unique.

When adding a duplicate key the old value is replaced (see [HashMap.put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-))

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a tricky question.  The key in HashMap must be unique.  If you want to store multiple elements on the same key, you can save a collection like:

```
Map<Integer, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, the following method would return a List.

```
map.get(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but If someone still have this problem who want to save values to a HashMap using duplicate key you can use

```
MultiMap<>;
```

here are the steps:
add

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre'
```

then replace your `HashMap<>` with `MultiMap<>`

you will be able to save duplicate keys!

Comment: Create variable like this: Multimap<String, String> wordMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();