# How to know if there are two identical elements in the same map in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, computer-science

I used nested map,

```
Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>> scheduleMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and I put three elements in the map, `studentId`, `subject`, `major`.

As examples for input,

```
    scheduleMap1.add("30600001", "INFO1105", "IT");
    scheduleMap1.add("30600001", "ELEC1603", "ElecEng");
    scheduleMap1.add("30600002", "INFO1103", "IT");
    scheduleMap1.add("30600003", "INFO1003", "IT");
    scheduleMap1.add("30600001", "ELEC1601", "ElecEng");
    scheduleMap1.add("30600002", "INFO1003", "IT");
    scheduleMap1.add("30600002", "ELEC1603", "ElecEng");
    scheduleMap1.add("30600001", "INFO1003", "IT");
```

were put in the map.

The final purpose was that, for each student id, 30600001, 30600002 and 30600003, if there are two identical majors stored in whichever in the key, the count should be increased.

For example, as shown in the example, 30600001 has two "IT" and two "ElecEng" each as its major element. So the count should be equal to 2.

For studentId, 30600002, it has two "IT" but has only one "ElecEng" as its major element so the count should be 1.

I could achieve my goal by coding like this:

```
for(Entry<String, Map<String, List<String>>> studentId : scheduleMap.entrySet()) {

 for(Entry<String, List<String>> subject : studentId.getValue().entrySet()) 
 {
    for(String major : subject.getValue())
    {
      if(major.contains("IT"))
      {
         it++;
      } else if(major.contains("ElecEng")) {
          elec++;

        }
          if(it >= 2 || elec >= 2)
          {
            count++;
          }
    }
```

however, is there any way to get the counts by not pointing out the finding major like `major.contains("IT")` and `major.contains("ElecEng")`?

I really want to get the count increased by doing like,

```
if(everytime key.subject.major has two identical elements)
{
   count++;
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Maps don't have an `add` method and the `put` method would require a key + value, not 3 values. So your example doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Shouldn't it be here `scheduleMap1.put (key, value)` instead of `scheduleMap1.add(a, b, c);`?

Comment: Oh, for putting three elements in a map, I created add method separately

Comment: Putting elements works fine, but what I dont get is the way to find two identical elements in a certain key without pointing out the subject name...

Comment: A key in map will store only one value. if you put another value in map it will override the already stored value, unless the values has same hashcode. Is the  values your adding has same hashcode. if not, it is not possible to find two identical values using map.

Answer (score 4):

Map in general don’t support two key-value set with the same key. Each and every key must be unique. 
[Refer to this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290968/can-i-get-all-the-values-of-hashmap-elements-having-the-same-keys-java)